# Split a list into sublists based on certain string

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, split

I am pretty new to python, so my question is:

I have a list like this:

```
L = ['Name1', 'String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'Name2', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6', ...]
```

I would like to convert it into a new list in which all the strings after a certain 'name' are in a sub-list with the name like:

```
L2 = [['Name1', 'String1', 'String2', 'String3'],['Name2', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6'],[...]]
```

Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: The data is always separated every 4 elements?

Comment: @eyllanesc I guess OP is looking to split whenever `Name.*` appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that there is a function isname() that tells us whether an element of list L is a name:

```
Lsub = []
L2 = []
for e in L:
    if isname(e):
        if Lsub: 
            L2.append(Lsub)
        Lsub = [e]
    else:
        Lsub.append(e)
L2.append(Lsub)
```

Comment: What does this line do?
`if Lsub: `

Comment: @kurious: Lsub evaluates as False when it is an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most Pythonic, but:

```
import re

L = ['Name1', 'String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'Name2', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6']

l_temp = re.split(r'(Name\d+)', ' '.join(L))

new_L = [[item] + l_temp[i+1].strip().split(' ') 
        for i, item in enumerate(l_temp) if item.startswith('Name')]

print new_L
```

["Flat is better than nested", but "simple is better than complex" and "readability counts"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3), so...